# How to select rows between date and time in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, between

There is a table that has three columns. ID, Date and Time. I need to select rows that are between 2014/01/04 and 2014/06/15 (specified by green) where start time is 12:00:00 and finish time is 20:00:00 (specified by blue). How can I select all blue rows?

I used this method:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $database_table 
WHERE UTCdate BETWEEN '{$from_date}' AND '{$to_date}' 
AND satellite_derived_time BETWEEN CAST('{$from_time}' AS UNSIGNED) 
AND CAST('{$to_time}' AS UNSIGNED)";
```

But it's not right because time doesn't always increase like date.
[image]

I need all rows that have a date between 2014/01/04 and 2014/06/15 AND also have a time between 12:00:00 and 20:00:00.

Date is OK because I can use between from_date and to_date but my problem is time. Look at table, Time isn't increasing like date, so I can't use between for time. For example my time start from 135911 and end with 020719 so it just lists rows that are between these two numbers but I need all blue rows like row 6 that is not in this range.

Comment: What type is the date and time columns?

Comment: What variables do you input in the query?

Comment: Date is int and time is varcahr.

Comment: Variables are fromDate, toDate, fromTime and toTime.

Comment: What are the values of the two time varialbles?

Comment: @Dan Bracuk: Start time is 12:00:00 and finish time is 20:00:00 and in table is 120000 and 200000 saved as varchar.

Comment: What happens if you strip out the colons?

Comment: @Dan Bracuk: I can't understand you?!

Comment: This question is not clear. Please improve it. Do you need all rows that have a date+time between 2014/01/04 12:00:00 and 2014/06/15 20:00:00 or do you need all rows that have a date between 2014/01/04 and 2014/06/15 *AND* also have a time between 12:00:00 and 20:00:00. It's not the same thing, and it is not stated clearly.

Comment: @Frazz: I improved my question.

Comment: Instead of sending '12:00:00' as the $from_time variable and casting it, send '120000', and don't do anything with it.  Leave everything as a numeric string.

Comment: BETWEEN is evaluated on a row-by-row basis. Table ordering has nothing to do with wether you can use a BETWEEN or not to filter data. With the problem stated as you did a BETWEEN on date and a BETWEEN on time should work. What was the result set you got? And what the result set you expected?

Comment: Not related to your question, but the fact that the table name is a variable is disturbing.

Comment: This is what I expect: List all rows that start from 2014/01/04 (2014014) and end with 2014/06/15 (20140615). Now in this list give me all rows that time start from 12:00:00 (120000) and finish with 20:00:00 (200000). In the table I need all blue rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer:
**UTCdate** is *date* and **satellite_derived_time** is *time* in table.

```
//Get the accessible first day from date range between '$from_date' and '$to_date'. Then get the first time that is bigger or equal to '$from_time'. If there is no time bigger than '$from_time' in the specified first day so it get the first time of next day.
{
  //Find the first accessible day between two given date range.
  $first_day = "(SELECT UTCdate FROM $database_table WHERE UTCdate BETWEEN '{$from_date}' AND '{$to_date}' LIMIT 1)";
  $result = mysql_query($first_day) or die('Query faild'.mysql_error());
  $first_day_rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


  //Get id of the nearest day that is biggest or equal to '$from_date' and '$from_time'.
  $first_time = "(SELECT id FROM $database_table WHERE UTCdate = '{$first_day_rows['UTCdate']}' AND satellite_derived_time >= CAST('{$from_time}' AS UNSIGNED) LIMIT 1)";
  $result = mysql_query($first_time) or die('Query faild'.mysql_error());
  $first_time_rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


  if((!$first_time_rows) && $first_day_rows['UTCdate'])
  {
      $first_day = "(SELECT UTCdate FROM $database_table WHERE UTCdate > '{$first_day_rows['UTCdate']}' LIMIT 1)";

      $first_time = "(SELECT id FROM $database_table WHERE UTCdate = $first_day AND satellite_derived_time >= CAST('0' AS UNSIGNED) LIMIT 1)";
  }
}





//Get the accessible last day from date range between '$from_date' and '$to_date'. Then get the last time that is smaller or equal to '$to_time'. If there is no time lesser than '$to_time' in the specified last day so it get the last time of previous day.
{
  //Find the last accessible day between two given date range.
  $last_day = "(SELECT UTCdate FROM $database_table WHERE UTCdate BETWEEN '{$from_date}' AND '{$to_date}' ORDER BY UTCdate DESC LIMIT 1)";
  $result = mysql_query($last_day) or die('Query faild'.mysql_error());
  $last_day_rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);



  //Get id of the nearest day that is biggest or equal to '$from_date' and '$from_time'.
  $last_time = "(SELECT id FROM $database_table WHERE UTCdate = '{$last_day_rows['UTCdate']}' AND satellite_derived_time <= CAST('{$to_time}' AS UNSIGNED) ORDER BY satellite_derived_time DESC LIMIT 1)";
  $result = mysql_query($last_time) or die('Query faild'.mysql_error());
  $last_time_rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


  if((!$last_time_rows) && $last_day_rows['UTCdate'])
  {
      $last_day = "(SELECT UTCdate FROM $database_table WHERE UTCdate < '{$last_day_rows['UTCdate']}' ORDER BY UTCdate DESC LIMIT 1)";          

      $last_time = "(SELECT id FROM $database_table WHERE UTCdate = $last_day AND satellite_derived_time <= CAST('235959' AS UNSIGNED) ORDER BY satellite_derived_time DESC LIMIT 1)";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 1**:

> This work for me exactly:
>
> ```
> $query = "SELECT * FROM $database_table 
>            WHERE UTCdate BETWEEN '{$from_date}' AND '{$to_date}' 
>              AND satellite_derived_time 
>                    BETWEEN CAST('{$from_time}' AS UNSIGNED) 
>                        AND CAST('{$to_time}' AS UNSIGNED)";
> ```
>
> but doesn't show all rows I need. It just shows me rows that are between `12:00:00` and `20:00:00` and for example doesn't show row 6 because its time is `23`

Change part of your query like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM $database_table 
 WHERE str_to_date( concat( UTCdate, ' ', satellite_derived_time ),
                    '%Y%m%d %H%i%s' )
 BETWEEN str_to_date( concat( '{$from_date}', ' ', '{$from_time}' ),
                      '%Y%m%d %H%i%s' )
     AND str_to_date( concat( '{$to_date}', ' ', '{$to_time}' ),
                      '%Y%m%d %H%i%s' )
```

---

Assuming your input for dates is in `yyyymmdd` format and for time is in `H:i:s` format.

```
select * from $database_table 
 where str_to_date( UTCdate, '%Y%m%d' ) 
        between str_to_date( '$from_date', '%Y%m%d' ) 
            and str_to_date( '$to_date', '%Y%m%d' ) 
   and str_to_date( satellite_derived_time, '%H%i%s' )
        /*
           between str_to_date( '$fromTime', '%Y%m%d' ) 
               and str_to_date( '$toTime', '%Y%m%d' )
        */
        -- or, if you use straight time format, then 
        between '$fromTime' and '$toTime'
```

Use prepared statement to bind variables.

Comment: Thanks but don't give the result. This work for me exactly: $query = "SELECT * FROM $database_table WHERE UTCdate BETWEEN '{$from_date}' AND '{$to_date}' AND satellite_derived_time BETWEEN CAST('{$from_time}' AS UNSIGNED) AND CAST('{$to_time}' AS UNSIGNED)"; but doesn't show all rows I need. It just shows me rows that are between 12:00:00 and 20:00:00 and for example doesn't show row 6 because its time is 23.

Comment: By `startTime` do you mean that on `from_date`?

Answer (score 1):

Write the php code so that your database processes this command.

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable 
WHERE UTCdate BETWEEN  20140104 and 20140615   -- these are integers
AND satellite_derived_time BETWEEN '120000' and '200000' -- these are strings
```

Comment: What about row 6? it is '234459'. I need all blue rows.

Comment: Your question says that the time has to be between noon and 8 pm.  Row 6 is 1 second shy of 11:45 PM, not within that time range.  What am I missing?